# Comparing Blobs or Basic Shapes

Tags: c#, image-processing, aforge

I'm trying to use blob detection to process an image. When a blob looks similar to a sample blob I want to split the logic but I'm having difficulty with comparing the two blobs.

I'm currently using AForge, my best lead is to use the outer points of the blobs and reconstruct the basic shape of the blobs. Theses shapes are black and white and a known shape so it wouldn't be impossible.

Is there a simpler way to compare the difference between two blobs?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AForge.NET#Discontinuation_of_free_public_support_and_future_development

Answer (score 0):

Detecting shapes of any form could be done using Haar cascade classifiers. I'm more used to OpenCV (https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/objdetect/doc/cascade_classification.html)

Apparently, AForge doesn't come with Haar classifiers itself, but there seems to be a decent library containing `HaarCascade`.

So you might want to have a look here: http://accord-framework.net/docs/html/T_Accord_Vision_Detection_HaarCascade.htm

I've used the following blog post for my OpenCV case back in the days: https://coding-robin.de/2013/07/22/train-your-own-opencv-haar-classifier.html